# is Node.js a Javascript runtime environment or a Javascript framework?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js and trying to understand it. I have read on the web saying Node.js is a JavaScript runtime environment. I liked that description. But a book title in Amazon.com says it is a JavaScript framework. So I am confused. Where do you classify Node.js? Is it a JavaScript runtime environment or a JavaScript framework? Actually it really doesn't matter, but knowing it clearly helps talking about it.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/299152/is-node-js-a-framework

Answer (score 0):

> Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript
>   engine. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that
>   makes it lightweight and efficient. Node.js' package ecosystem, npm,
>   is the largest ecosystem of open source libraries in the world. [0]

[0] https://nodejs.org/en/

In short, the creators consider it a JavaScript runtime.